# Remove custom stop words from pandas dataframe not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, tf-idf, stop-words

I am trying to remove a custom list of stop words, but its not working.

```
desc = pd.DataFrame(description, columns =['description'])
print(desc)
```

Which gives the following results

```
description
188693  The Kentucky Cannabis Company and Bluegrass He...
181535                                Ohio County Sheriff
11443   According to new reports from federal authorit...
213919  KANSAS CITY, Mo. (AP)The Chiefs will be withou...
171509  The crew of Insight, WCNY's weekly public affa...
...                                                   ...
2732    The Arkansas Supreme Court on Thursday cleared...
183367  Larry Pegram, co-owner of Pure Ohio Wellness, ...
134291  Joe Biden will spend the next five months pres...
239270  Find out where your Texas representatives stan...
246070  SAN TAN VALLEY — Two men have been charged wit...

[9875 rows x 1 columns]
```

I found the following code here, but it doesn't seem to work

```
remove_words = ["marijuana", "cannabis", "hemp", "thc", "cbd"]
pat = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(w) for w in remove_words])
desc.assign(new_desc=desc.replace(dict(string={pat: ''}), regex=True))
```

Which produces the following results

```
    description                                                    new_desc
188693  The Kentucky Cannabis Company and Bluegrass He...   The Kentucky Cannabis Company and Bluegrass He...
181535  Ohio County Sheriff                                 Ohio County Sheriff
11443   According to new reports from federal authorit...   According to new reports from federal authorit...
213919  KANSAS CITY, Mo. (AP)The Chiefs will be withou...   KANSAS CITY, Mo. (AP)The Chiefs will be withou...
171509  The crew of Insight, WCNY's weekly public affa...   The crew of Insight, WCNY's weekly public affa...
...     ...     ...
2732    The Arkansas Supreme Court on Thursday cleared...   The Arkansas Supreme Court on Thursday cleared...
183367  Larry Pegram, co-owner of Pure Ohio Wellness, ...   Larry Pegram, co-owner of Pure Ohio Wellness, ...
134291  Joe Biden will spend the next five months pres...   Joe Biden will spend the next five months pres...
239270  Find out where your Texas representatives stan...   Find out where your Texas representatives stan...
246070  SAN TAN VALLEY — Two men have been charged wit...   SAN TAN VALLEY — Two men have been charged wit...

9875 rows × 2 columns
```

As you can see, the stop words weren't removed. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the case, simplify pattern,

```
remove_words = ["marijuana", "cannabis", "hemp", "thc", "cbd"]
pat = '|'.join(remove_words)
desc['new_desc'] = desc.description.str.lower().replace(pat,'', regex=True)


    description                                         new_desc
0   The Kentucky Cannabis Company and Bluegrass He...   the kentucky company and bluegrass he...
1   Ohio County Sheriff ohio county sheriff
2   According to new reports from federal authorit...   according to new reports from federal authorit...
3   KANSAS CITY, Mo. (AP)The Chiefs will be mariju...   kansas city, mo. (ap)the chiefs will be witho...
4   The crew of Insight, WCNY's weekly public affa...   the crew of insight, wcny's weekly public affa...
```

Comment: It sort of worked, but I'm not sure I can explain what it did. It looks like it put 'new_desc' in the same column as the original 'desc' df. That's not what I wanted to do. I just wanted to remove the custom stop words.

Comment: @MaxxABillion, the code above creates a new column called new_desc. Not sure what you mean by "it put 'new_desc' in the same column as the original 'desc' df"

Comment: I figured it out. It was displaying weird. I dropped the old column and was good to go. Still ran into another issue. I'll post another question soon